# Can't change value of android layout file elements programatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a java class in my android project that creates my custom dialog. But when I want to set a text or another properties to my custom dialog layout file, I cant!

No change take place when I use setText to change textView of my dialog layout in my activity or in custom dialog java class.

here is my custom dialog layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/dark_primary"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/alert"
    android:textSize="@dimen/alert_title_font_size"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:fontFamily="@font/berlin_regular"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is my dialog builder java class :

```
package com.x.Dialog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.orhanobut.dialogplus.DialogPlus;
import com.orhanobut.dialogplus.OnItemClickListener;
import com.orhanobut.dialogplus.ViewHolder;
import com.x.x.R;

public class CustomAlertDialog {

public Context context;
public Activity activity;
public TextView textView;

public CustomAlertDialog(Context context, Activity activity, ViewHolder viewHolder){

    this.context = context;
    this.activity = activity;
    View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_1, null);
    textView = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("Test");
    DialogPlus dialog = DialogPlus.newDialog(this.context)
            .setContentHolder(viewHolder)
            .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(DialogPlus dialog, Object item, View view, int position) {
                }
            })
            .setExpanded(true)  // This will enable the expand feature, (similar to android L share dialog)
            .create();
    dialog.show();
}
}
```

In the above codes `textView.setText("Test");` does not work: it will **not** change the field content.  The default text that I set in xml (@string/alert) is still shown!

Comment: @GhostCat thank you I edited my topic

Comment: check if this works for you  dialog.setView(dialogView) .. add this before dialog.show

Comment: @AdeelTurk I'm using another library to build this dialog an it doesn't have this method (setView).

Comment: then change the library source or write your own library or ask that developer who wrote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so looking at the library you are using i found this `.setContentHolder(new ViewHolder(view))`

so change your code from

```
DialogPlus dialog = DialogPlus.newDialog(this.context)
        .setContentHolder(viewHolder)
        .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(DialogPlus dialog, Object item, View view, int position) {
            }
        })
        .setExpanded(true)  // This will enable the expand feature, (similar to android L share dialog)
        .create();
```

to

```
  DialogPlus dialog = DialogPlus.newDialog(this.context)
        .setContentHolder(new ViewHolder(dialogView ))
        .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(DialogPlus dialog, Object item, View view, int position) {
            }
        })
        .setExpanded(true)  // This will enable the expand feature, (similar to android L share dialog)
        .create();
```

Comment: thank you so much! it worked perfectly. but could you explain what is the difference between the way I set the layout to dialog builder and the way that you did that?!

Comment: you were notr passing your custom view to teh dialog.. so i passed it in the viewholder object in short new ViewHolder(dialogView )  this is the magic spell here abra ka dabra boom

Comment: and (https://github.com/orhanobut/dialogplus) this link helped me so you should be reading the git instructions  given here  first .. happy coding